# Create similar to .exe file for mac os

Tags: macos, applescript, script

I need create a non reable executable script for mac os.
Example. I have .exe for windows user and they cant open and see the source code. Similarly i need to create executable application for mac os.

Comment: Questions on how to turn AppleScript or bash scripts into executable binaries have come up before, I‘ve linked two of them on top of your question (there probably are more to be found via the Search bar on top). If the answers to these questions don‘t address your needs, please *edit* your question to add details.

Comment: @nohillside you can still access the source code of an AppleScript application: either by opening it in Script Editor, or by browsing the package. Ultimately, unless you're able to compile the script into some kind of binary, then an executable script will always be able to be read. The real question is, why does it matter if a user can see what the script does?

Comment: A script can be exported as run only, in which case it can’t be opened in the Script Editor, but just like any other object file (including Windows executables), the raw code can be viewed in a hex editor or disassembled.  If this is some kind of attempt at obscuring sensitive information, a much better plan is to not place it in the executable at all.

Comment: @benwiggy Absolutely! Obscuring code to hide secrets never works. But let‘s see whether the OP got the information they are looking for from the existing answer or whether they come back to clarify their question.